# Pivot in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, pivot

Imagine a table primary keyed by date and name.

```
|Date|Name|Value|
|D1  |   A|    2|
|D1  |   B|    3|
|D2  |   A|    3|
|D2  |   C|    1|
```

How would one write a SQLAlchemy query yielding (date, value) pairs where the values are all of the values for all of the names on that date? The length of the value tuple would be `len(distinct(Name))` and missing values would contain some sentinel value (e.g. None).

```
i.e.
[
(D1, 2, 3, None),
(D2, 3, None, 1),
...
]
```

I'm not asking for a full answer here in order to get me to approve. If you can tell me what concepts to search for/read in the documentation (or really, point me to *anything* useful or related), I'll (try to) figure it out myself and post an update.

[No pandas solutions please]

The easy answer is to load the query in long form and do the pivoting in numpy using numpy.searchsorted, but if the submitted answer uses this, I would be interested in some performance diagnostics to compare with the simple solution.

Comment: What determines a particular name's position in the tuple? I.e. why is A in position 1, B position 2 etc.?

Comment: Preferably those would be ordered according to a list that I could provide (i.e. arbitrary ordering as far as we're aware).

Comment: Your problem looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089661

Comment: @SGP - I don't think that answer addresses missing values.

Comment: Could post some code!

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend not to do it in on the `SQL Server` side, unless you have a huge amount of data (and even in this case I am not sure it has significant positive performance impact).

Instead, use different tools where they excel:

- `MS-SQL` (or other RDBMS) to store data
- `SQLAlchemy` to insert/query that data
- `numpy` routines or `pandas.pivot` to pivot the data

The code below is self-contained, running (with `sqlite`) and shows how to do get to the final result you desire:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import pandas as pd

_db_uri = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
engine = create_engine(_db_uri, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(String)
    name = Column(String)
    value = Column(Integer)

def _test():
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session()

    def _add_test_data():
        rows = [
            MyTable(date="D1", name="A", value=2),
            MyTable(date="D1", name="B", value=3),
            MyTable(date="D2", name="A", value=3),
            MyTable(date="D2", name="C", value=1),
        ]
        session.add_all(rows)
        session.commit()

    # create test data
    _add_test_data()

    # use `sa` to query data from the database
    # q = session.query(MyTable)  # all columns
    q = session.query(MyTable.date, MyTable.name, MyTable.value)  # explicit

    # read data into pandas directly from the query `q`
    df = pd.read_sql(q.statement, q.session.bind)
    print(df)

    # pivot the results
    df_pivot = df.pivot(index="date", columns="name", values="value")
    print(df_pivot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _test()
```

Comment: Sorry, no pandas please.

Comment: @frickskit why hate pandas :) I would say pandas is ideal for this kinda work

Comment: I simply can't use it, I agree that it's useful and nice :)

Comment: You do get an upvote though :) I'll also approve if no one posts a non-pandas solution.